# Customizer in Wordpress issues in the console 403?

Tags: wordpress

In the WordPress evolve + theme, there are settings in the customizer using the Kirki plugin, when you choose a setting, for example, changing the color of the theme, nothing changes, and the console displays a 403 error. Plug-ins all turned off, it still does not help. Tell me, please, how can I correct these errors?

Here is a screenshot  with errors in console http://prntscr.com/nygz28

**Updated**

With default WP theme Twenty Nineteen the is only 1 error Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, 1; mode=block: expected semicolon at character position 13. The default protections will be applied. 
 and customizer saves changes.

Errors in the console when customizer is closed

Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, 1; mode=block: expected semicolon at character position 13. The default protections will be applied.

When it opened there are more errors
Mixed Content: The page at was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**And in error_log file there are warnings**

[06-Sep-2018 11:33:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'no_wordpress_errors' not found or invalid function name in /home/camlkosr/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286
[06-Sep-2018 15:57:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'no_wordpress_errors' not found or invalid function name in /home/camlkosr/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286
[06-Sep-2018 15:59:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /home/camlkosr/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/includes/core/um-filters-fields.php on line 645
[06-Sep-2018 15:59:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /home/camlkosr/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/includes/core/um-filters-fields.php on line 648
[06-Sep-2018 20:27:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'no_wordpress_errors' not found or invalid function name in /home/camlkosr/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Comment: Please try this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

Comment: Hi! Thank you, but this plugin resolves only one error with Mixed Content.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the hosting settings, it was needed to disable Mod_security in apache.

Comment: Well, that was probably causing the 403, but it wasn't the problem. Can't tell for sure without seeing all the details, but I would guess your host turned on a mod security rule to prevent PHP info leakages, and the warning messages triggered that rule. The real cause was badly written PHP, that threw those messages in the first place.